# Can the data-visualization and visualization tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I think the [data-visualization](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) tag can be merged into the [visualization](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization)  tag.

Both solve the same purpose.  And the [visualization](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization) has a wiki for itself too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems right to me. I merged them.